# Mapping data into correct format Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This should be an easy one but I am not getting it right. Looked around on Google and SO and found a few suggestions but can't get any of them to work for me.

I need to output a specific data structure which is an array of hashes that contains an index for each hash:

```
[ id => {:key=>"foo", :value=>"bar"}]
```

I have a Class object ("Foo"), that I need to map into the above structure. I have come this far:

```
[{:key=>"personal", :value=>"age"}]
```

...Using this Code:

```
check = Foo.find(1)
check.collect{|r| {:key => r.name, :value => r.type}}
```

What I'd like to achieve is to add an index to the hash above. The index's value should be "check.id".

I think that this might be heading in the right direction but not sure (Results in an error):

```
check.group_by {|r| r.id }.collect{ |r| {:key => r.name, :value => r.type}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
check.collect{|r| {r.id.to_s => {:key => r.name, :value => r.type}}}
```

Actually I assume you want to get hash of hashes:

```
Hash[ *check.collect { |r| [r.id.to_s, {:key => r.name, :value => r.type}] }.flatten ]
```